# U8glib pass parameter to "int draw(String msg)" Draw function

Tags: arduino

While using U8glib I'm trying to pass a value to the draw function but can't get it to work.
Always get an error in line "lcd_1.drawStr( 0, 10, sms);"
no matching function for call to 'U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X32::drawStr(int, int, String&)'
Is it even possible to do, to use a variable on "lcd_1.drawStr( 0, 10, sms);" ?
Tryed the same thing using Adafruit lib and it works.
Thanks

```
#include "U8glib.h"
U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X32 lcd_1(U8G_I2C_OPT_FAST);

void setup() {
  lcd_1.setFont(u8g_font_unifont);
}

int draw(String sms){
          lcd_1.drawStr( 0, 10, sms);
}
void loop() {
   lcd_1.firstPage(); 
      do {
        draw("boo")
        } while( lcd_1.nextPage() );
   delay(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `drawStr` method signature is defined as:

```
u8g_uint_t drawStr(u8g_uint_t x, u8g_uint_t y, const char *s)
```

And there isn't an implicit cast from the Arduino `String` class to a `const char *`.

You should be able to obtain a `char *` by using String's `c_str()` method:

```
lcd_1.drawStr(0, 10, sms.c_str());
```